# Able to enter text into disabled numeric input field in Firefox

Tags: html, reactjs, firefox

I'm seeing some weird behavior on Firefox 60.0 which does not appear in Chrome. I have the following disabled `FormControl` tag:

```
<FormControl type="number" disabled="true" defaultValue="15" ... />
```

In Chrome, a mouse hover shows the appropriate `not-allowed` cursor type and I cannot click or type into the field. However, on Firefox, even though I see a `not-allowed` cursor type, I can fully edit the field. This does not affect any backend logic of mine but it's a weird usability thing.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug on mozilla's end